# Python requests lib. Json requests

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I have a problem trying to format a JSON in a request, (I am using the `requests` library).

This is what I am supposed to send, this is a correct requests where a receive a `200 OK`:

```
{
   "servers":[
      {
         "host":"willi.ci.hi",
         "port":"2921",
         "text":[
            "A: willi.ci.hi 2921 william 12345"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "share":true
}
```

This is what I send with `requests`, in order to simulate the request:

```
json = {'host': 'willi.ci.hi', 
        'port': '2921', 
        'lines': 'C: willi.ci.hi 2921 william 12345', 
        'share': 'true'}

response = requests.post('http://www.test.com/validate', json=json, proxies=proxy, headers=headers, cookies=cookie)
```

And this is what I capture in with a proxy (with Burp proxy), what I really send:

```
{
   "share":"true",
   "host":"willi.ci.hi",
   "text":"A: willi.ci.hi 2921 william 12345",
   "port":"2921"
}
```

And I get a `500 Server Internal Error`.

All the headers are right, my problem is the Json I am sending =(

Comment: So why don't you send what you supposed to send?

Comment: I want to automatize that. I want to perform a valid request, so I have captured how a good request is made but I am still not able to replicate it

Comment: The dictionary you are sending looks nothing like the data from the "successful" request.  What is confusing about that? For example, the good data is a dictionary with a top level "servers" key; the dictionary you are sending does not.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I just needed to format what I was capturing in the proxy.

Comment: Can you tell me a good Json viewer, where I can go from this: `{"share": "true", "servers": [{"host": "willi.ci.hi", "text": ["C: willi.ci.hi 2921 william 12345"], "port": "2921"}]}` to a well-formatted JSON separated line by line¿? Thank you

Comment: @aDoN Try http://jsonlint.com/ or http://jsoneditoronline.org/